# Solution to $Mx-x^2=0$ where $x^2$ is the square of the elements of vector $x$

Tags: nonlinear-system, hadamard-product, algebraic-equations

I have been trying to find the solutions for

$$Mx=x\circ x$$ 
where $\circ$ is the element wise product.

One solution is $x=0$. But there is another solution $x\neq 0$, if $M$ has a real positive eigenvalue.
( $M$ is invertible, and quasipositive).

Any hints or references where to find more on this?

It is similar to the logistic equation, but multivariable with cross terms.

Cheers

Comment: Depending on the $M$ matrix, the iteration $$x_+ = {\sqrt {Mx}}$$ can converge rather quickly. Note that the square root is applied element-wise, and the starting point should not be the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you. It seems there is no analytical expression, and I will always need to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\text{diag}(x)$ the diagonal matrix whose elements are the elements of $x$, then you have:
$$
(M-\text{diag}(x))x=0
$$
This implies:
$$
x^T(M-\text{diag}(x))^T(M-\text{diag}(x))x=0
$$

Which is a polynomial equation on the entries of $x$, hence you should be able to find a solution with numerical methods, but I doubt you would find an analytical one.

Comment: Thank you. I have a couple of ways to solve it numerically. Since it is a problem "simple" to formulate i had hopes for an existing analytic solution.